# How do I get data from an api and then send a push notification to my device if something changed (with firebase)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, api

I'm creating an android app in Java which is supposed to check third party APIs for any changes in the cryptocurrency balance and if there are any, then it should send a push notification to my app.

Originally I was thinking about doing this with an AlarmManager but the drawback is that it drains the battery to much. I've heard about Firebase and I would like to use it in my project, but I didn't find any source or documentation on how I could continually get the API data.

I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction or give me an example (I don't know how to actually get the data with firebase, but I saw a lot of documentation on push notifications and I know how to compare the data).

Answer (score 1):

You should give it a try to "Firebase cloud functions". Firebase has a lot os features (notification, storage, database, ...), but sometimes you need to integrate them, or make them work by themselves.

Cloud functions uses javascript (no need to be an expert, with the basic you'll be able to start and learn as you go). So you'll be able to: create a javascript code that uses your API to "listen" to events, like currency changes. Inside this change callback, you'll be able to call a Firebase Notification API function to send the notification with the data you want. Not exactly a hard work, but It will take sometime to get the javascript basic and Firebase API's.

You can start with the cloud function documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions?hl=pt-br

Comment: I'm familiar with JavaScript and I was looking at the firebase functions, but I thought there might be a better way of doing this.